# Value I'm trying to get is always null

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon

In my application I'm using a ribbon control, on this ribbon is a button.
When I click the button it should get the selected value from the datagrid in my view.

Now when I click the button the value it gets is always `null`.

This is my code:

**View1.xaml**

```
<ScrollViewer Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="stackpanelLocked"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RandomHeaderX" Binding="{Binding Path=X}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RandomHeaderY" Binding="{Binding Path=Y}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Viewmodel**

```
//get selected item value
string lastSelectedValue;
private Model _test;        
public Model Test 
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        if(Test != null)
            this.lastSelectedValue = string.Format("Variabele X: {0} Variabele Y: {1}", Test.X, Test.Y);
    }
}

private ICommand _ClickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_ClickCommand == null)
            _ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(Execute),
                        new Func<bool>(CanExecute));
        return _ClickCommand;
    }
}

public bool CanExecute()
{
    return true;
}

public void Execute()
{
    if(lastSelectedValue != null)
        Clipboard.SetText(lastSelectedValue);  
}
```

**Model**

```
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }

public Model(int x, int y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

Extra info:

Every time I click in the datagrid it will actually fill the `string` `lastSelectedValue`.
But when I click the button on the ribbon it will say that the `lastSelectedValue` is  null.

**Collection stuff:**

```
public List<DatabaseClass.coord> AllCoords { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set; }
public ModuleARibbonTabModel()
{
    Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    GenerateDatas();
}

private void GenerateDatas()
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseClass.TestDatabaseEntities1 ())
    {
        AllCoords = ctx.coord.ToList();
    }
    foreach(DatabaseClass.coord f in AllCoords)
    {
        Collection.Add(new Model(Convert.ToInt32(f.Een.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(f.Twee.ToString())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your Collection property.

Comment: Does this have something to do with threads maybe?

Comment: With the code you've given there is no way for `lastSelectedValue` to be set to null after it has been set to a valid value. Since you say that it is being set by the datagrid ok, there must be a bug in code that you have not posted. Why don't you put a breakpoint on `lastSelectedValue` to see when it is being set back to null?

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the problem.
I don't think this is a good fix but this is what I changed:
I changed the `string lastSelectedValue` to a `static string lastSelectedValue`
This makes sure I can get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Bind to `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to read my question.
Why do people even upvote this.(not to be rude)
I already tried that before, and I even set it to value for testing if it worked(because someone else on this site said it should be value....).

Comment: Hi! I had the impression that you want to get the complete object your list is bound to. Than you should use SelectedItem. If you want only a value of your selected object, you should use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.

Comment: You have added some extra information. Are you sure, that the ribbon button and the view are bound to the datacontext instance?